# Typescript Error using react-daterange-picker "No overload matches this call."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-calendar, react-daterange-picker

When I try to use [`react-daterange-picker`](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker) in my React Typescript app, I get the error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RangeProps<DateRangePicker> | SingleProps<DateRangePicker> | Readonly<RangeProps<DateRangePicker>> | Readonly<...>): DateRangePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'Moment | (MomentRange & typeof import("/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts")) | DateRange | undefined'.
      Type 'Date[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Moment': format, startOf, endOf, add, and 80 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props<DateRangePicker>, context: any): DateRangePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'Moment | (MomentRange & typeof import("/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment.d.ts")) | DateRange | undefined'.
      Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.  TS2769

    20 |         <DateRangePicker 
    21 |             onChange={onChange}
  > 22 |             value={value}
       |             ^
    23 |         />
    24 |     )
    25 | }
```

My code is based on the [official example in the package repo](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker#usage).

Why is there a Typescript error here, and how can we fix it?

**React Typescript code:**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateRangePicker from 'react-daterange-picker';

export function Foo(): JSX.Element {

    const [ value, onChange ] = useState([new Date(), new Date()]);

    return (
        <DateRangePicker 
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the one line you changed from the example was the import.

```
import DateRangePicker from 'react-daterange-picker';
```

This line does not import the module you linked to in your question. That imports  [`react-daterange-picker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-daterange-picker), but you linked to [`@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker). Those are two completely different modules.

Instead install `@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker` and it's types package `@types/wojtekmaj__react-datetimerange-picker`. Then it should work like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

change your import line

```
import DateRangePicker from 'react-daterange-picker';
```

to

```
import DateRangePicker from '@wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker';
```

If package not installed then:

```
npm install @wojtekmaj/react-daterange-picker
```

Hope this will help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I added the type definition in `@types`. You can install it by doing `npm install --save @types/wojtekmaj__react-daterange-picke`